# A simple question about an homeomorphism.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, projective-space

I already proved that the real projective line $\mathbb{R}P^1$ is homeomorphic to the quotient $S^1/\sim$, where $\sim$ is an equivalence relation in $S^1$ which identifies antipodal points.

> **Question.** How can prove that $S^1/ \sim$ is homeomorphic to the closed upper semicircle with the two endpoints identified?

Thanks!

Comment: You can, for instance, guess what one homeomorphism ought to be, and then show that it is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Hint: there's a fairly obvious map from the upper semicircle to $S^1/\sim$.

Comment: @user3482749Thanks for your comment. I would like an homeomorphism from the upper semicircle with the two end points identifies to $S^1/ \sim$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p : S^1 \to X  = S^1/\sim$ be the quotient map and $q : S^1_+ \to X$ be the restriction to the  closed upper semicircle. It is a closed map since $S^1_+$ is compact and $X$ is Hausdorff, thus a quotient map. Clearly it identifies precisely the endpoints of $S^1_+$.

Comment: @PaulFrostThanks Does this reasoning apply even if instead of $S_+^1$ we have a semicircle of any radius?

Comment: Yes, you can easily modify the definition of $q$. Just use a homeomorphism from your semicircle to $S^1_+$.